# pypy apt corruption - circular dependency?

Tags: corruption, apt, pypy

I'm having a strange problem I can't get myself out of.
Any time I try to do something in apt, I get this problem
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 185 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up pypy (5.4.1+dfsg-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/pypy.postinst: 39: /var/lib/dpkg/info/pypy.postinst: pypycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package pypy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pypy-pkg-resources:
 pypy-pkg-resources depends on pypy; however:
  Package pypy is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pypy-pkg-resources (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pypy-setuptools:
 pypy-setuptools depends on pypy-pkg-resources (= 28.0.0-1); however:
  Package pypy-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
 pypy-setuptools depends on pypy; however:
  Package pypy is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pypy-setuptools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pypy
 pypy-pkg-resources
 pypy-setuptools

I think the root cause problem is pypy:
$ sudo dpkg --configure pypy
Setting up pypy (5.4.1+dfsg-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/pypy.postinst: 39: /var/lib/dpkg/info/pypy.postinst: pypycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package pypy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pypy

but not sure how to dig myself out of this one, as I can't reinstall, remove, or seem to do anything with it:

$ sudo apt-get remove pypy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pypy pypy-pkg-resources pypy-setuptools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 185 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 34.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 78437 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pypy-setuptools (28.0.0-1) ...
Removing pypy-pkg-resources (28.0.0-1) ...
Removing pypy (5.4.1+dfsg-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/pypy.prerm: 18: /var/lib/dpkg/info/pypy.prerm: pypyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing package pypy (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pypy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it seems like the problem is that for some reason, Debian isn't creating a symlink to pypy. Can easily be fixed by running `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pypy/bin/pypy-c /usr/bin/pypy` and then run `sudo apt-get install pypy` again, and all should be well with the world!

Hope this helps, if not you, somebody else who is Googling this.

Cheers,
Zzyzx

Comment: Can confirm this is still an issue in stretch.  Shouldn't the package installer create the necessary symlinks?

Comment: Yes, it should. Not sure what causes it. Haven't looked into the package to actually see what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever hits this again, here's the solution I found in the end:

1. Unblock the issue of not being able to do dpkg --config pypy by updating /usr/bin/pypycompile to use #!/usr/binpython as interpreter rather than the #!/usr/bin/pypy
2. Update /usr/lib/pypy/runtime.d/public_modules.rtupdate to not attempt to run pypyclean

So in other words, the solution was to just remove or disable any post install scripts that prevented completion.